# Como criar "canvas de html"? (acho que é novidade no html)

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estava olhando uns sites e reparei um site que montou esse exemplo aqui: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/hangouts. A principio eu não liguei mas depois quando vi o html dessa page vi que tem uma tag

```
<hangout-module></hangout-module>
```

que funciona como um 'canvas' só que para html. Queria saber se alguém sabe a respeito ou como criar elas...

### OBS: não me refiro a canvas de gráficos, falei canvas como exemplo!

Comment: Se possível, pense em um título melhor, pois a pergunta não tem nada a ver com o elemento `canvas` (infelizmente, eu não tenho nada a sugerir nesse sentido).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não me parece nada "nativo" ao HTML5, mas sim uma biblioteca externa chamada [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html) (*Edit:* como apontado pelo OP nos comentários, se trada de um *polyfill*). Repare nas primeiras linhas do código-fonte da página citada:

```
<script src="/static/webcomponents-bdconf/js/polymer-all/polymer.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="/static/webcomponents-bdconf/demos/components/hangouts/elements/hangouts.html">
```

Ou seja, primeiro ele coloca o script da biblioteca acima, depois ele importa um arquivo `hangouts.html` que contém, entre outras coisas:

```
<polymer-element name="hangout-module" attributes="from messages profile" on-close="close" on-minimize="minimize">
```

Assim, o arquivo acima **define** novas tags, e a biblioteca acima faz alguma "mágica" para permitir sua inclusão no HTML normal (i.e. para obter tais tags do documento HTML e transformá-la em algo de útil). Se você observar o código da definição, verá que ele usa outras definições feitas no próprio arquivo, que por sua vez usam apenas elementos HTML ordinários. Ou seja: no final das contas, vai tudo virar HTML simples.

O projeto Polymer se define como "um conjunto de *polyfills* para características emergentes em plataformas para a web" ("*A set of polyfills for emerging web platform features*"). Nesse caso em particular, ele está agindo como *polyfill* para a funcionalidade [**Shadow DOM**](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) / [**Custom Elements**](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/), no momento [somente suportada pelo Chrome e Opera](http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom) segundo o `caniuse.com` (porém **não consistentemente** - ver [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4871/215) e [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4866/como-criar-canvas-de-html-acho-que-e-novidade-no-html/4867?noredirect=1#comment7580_4867) do @Gabriel Gartz).

A especificação para essa funcionalide ainda está em estado de "rascuho" - podendo mudar bastante antes de ser publicado - de modo que é difícil encontrar exemplos práticos do mesmo. Sugiro então ler o que diz a especificação e/ou [a documentação sobre o mesmo no próprio projeto Polymer](https://github.com/polymer/ShadowDOM) (também contribuição do OP nos comentários).

Observação: não confundir a funcionalidade acima com o [elemento `canvas`](http://centralhtml5.sourceforge.net/Guia-do-elemento-Canvas-do-HTML5-para-desenvolvedores) - outro elemento previsto no HTML5, com objetivo de criar uma "área de desenho" em 2D [ou mesmo 3D](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL).

Comment: não, eu não confundi, falei canvas por causa do jeito que vi, uma tag normal que parecia html dentro de um canvas. rsrs Obrigado vou dar uma olhada mais aprofundada o/

Comment: @IagoBruno blz, não estava me referindo a você em particular, falei pra qualquer um que ler minha resposta. E sim, é perfeitamente possível que um desses "templates" tenha gerado um `canvas`...

Comment: acho que achei o que é, se não estiver errado isso é ShadowDOM. https://github.com/polymer/ShadowDOM

Comment: @IagoBruno Acho que você tem razão, isso é algo que [existe no \[rascunho do\] HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/). Vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: @mgibsonbr o ShadowDOM é suportado nativamente pelo Opera, porém está diferente da especificação da W3C e não é suportado pelo platform do Polymer. Na realidade o polymer como um todo não é suportado pelo Opera, foi abandonado pela equipe por causa das diferenças de API, apesar de ter os recursos disponíveis.

Comment: @GabrielGartz Obrigado pela informação, eu estava apenas citando (e linkando para) o `caniuse.com` - mas não sei quase nada dessa funcionalidade, exceto que está em estado de rascunho, então me parece até natural haverem divergências. Li [sua resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4871/215), e de fato ela explica [a funcionalidade em si] melhor que a minha.

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu quero ajudar, eu gostei da sua resposta, quis complementar. Estou trabalhando com projeto Polymer algum tempo, também fiz fork de vários dos sub-projetos deles, e estou adicionando compatibilidade com o Opera, não é uma tarefa simples, na versão 13 do Opera (que está em alpha) ele vai suportar totalmente o projeto pois será baseado no Blink. Agradeço seu comentário, abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Isso se trata de um **[Custom Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/)**, previsto na API do HTML5 para **[Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/)**.

Hoje a maioria dos browsers ainda não suportam nativamente, até porque muitas das partes as APIs que compõem o *Web Components* ainda estão sendo escritas.

Esse componente que você achou utiliza do [Polymer Project](http://www.polymer-project.org/), desenvolvido pela Google, que funciona na maioria dos browser modernos (menos no Opera 12), além dos recursos de polyfill fornecidos pela `platform.js` que compõe o Polymer, ele contém outros recursos muito interessantes que o tornam muito similar ao AngularJS e ainda mais fácil de desenvolver, recursos como **[TemplateBinding](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/template.html)** e outros, fazendo uso de `[Object.observer][5]`, [template element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-templates/) dentre vários recursos das próximas gerações de APIs do HTML5.

Você também pode incluir em qualquer site os **Custom Elements**, utilizando **HTMLImports**, claro que pra funcionar no seu browser vai precisar de polyfill pra isso, também disponível no *platform*.

Esses elementos ainda podem ter seus recursos, css e outras coisas isolados do seu DOM, utilizando o recurso de **[ShadowDOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/)**, que basicamente gera um documento dentro do elemento, de forma tornar isolados seus elementos internos.

No HTML já existe um **[elemento canvas](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/canvas)**, que é focado em desenho/processamento de imagens com contexto 2D e 3D. Mas talvez sua citação tenha relação com alguma outro tipo de interface que refere-se a canvas como componente. Mas no caso do HTML5 é como eu expliquei anteriormente são elementos personalizados.

Para saber mais sobre o assunto, recomendo essa [palestra do Zeno Rocha](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQtwIwAQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Q0-E_rZ_Cc&ei=h9H1Uoe0C-euyQGY3YDgBQ&usg=AFQjCNHgZaE533epxugGBiXms5h-9HDH8w&sig2=ZC0Aa651tIu095V9i_XB7Q) que é além de tudo inspiradora.

E a caráter de curiosidade a Mozilla também fez um projeto baseado no código fonte do Polymer, porém só com o básico dos Custom Elements, chamado de [X-Tags](http://x-tags.org/), tem compatibilidade com um número maior de browsers, mas não da suporte ao HTMLImports, apenas ao custom elements de uma forma um pouco modificada da API oficial.