# Pra que serve a tag <canvas>?

Tags: html5, canvas

Estava pesquisando algumas informações e vi que existe uma tag chamada `<canvas>` em HTML5.

- O que faz a tag canvas?
- Ela só serve para fazer formas geométricas?
- Se for possível e viável, poderiam dar um exemplo?

Nessa outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4866/como-criar-canvas-de-html-acho-que-%C3%A9-novidade-no-html), o AP fala sobre o mesmo elemento `<canvas>` ou não tem nada a ver com o do HTML5?

Comment: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3488/entendendo-a-tag-canvas-no-html-5.aspx

Comment: Não serve só para fazer desenhos. Animações também, inclusive jogos. Vou ver se acho um exemplo bom e simples o bastante e se conseguir, posto uma resposta.

Comment: É o tipo de pergunta que já estou ansioso pra ver a resposta +1

Comment: A tag <canvas> é como se fosse um quadro em branco, esperando para ser pintado com um poderoso pincel chamado Javascript. :)  Na verdade, é muito mais do que isso, com a tag <canvas> você consegue renderizar imagens, desenhar elementos complexos e criar animações.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O elemento `canvas` permite o desenvolvedor criar imagens via código. Tratando-se de uma página Web, controla-se o canvas com JavaScript. Não é limitado à formas geométricas, você pode inserir imagens, textos, vetores e controlar tudo com uma linguagem de programação. Ou seja, você pode criar animações, interações, vídeos e jogos. Varia conforme a necessidade e criatividade.

A sintaxe do elemento é simples:

```
<canvas>
  Fallback text for non-supported browsers
</canvas>
```

Isto é, se o navegador não possuir suporte, o texto interno será exibido na página. Por padrão, se suportado, o conteúdo do elemento é ignorado pelo navegador.

Sua configuração padrão de exibição é `display: block` e é suportado pela grande maioria dos navegadores. Veja no [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas).

[Tutorial de como utilizar o elemento `canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial).

A recomendação W3C do elemento pode ser encontrada aqui: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-canvas-element.html

#### Exemplo de prancheta de desenho com Canvas:

```js
function init() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  var pinta = false;
  var red = green = blue = 127;
  var rf = 1,
    gf = 1,
    bf = 1;
  var rm = getAleatorio();
  var gm = getAleatorio();
  var bm = getAleatorio();

  function desenha(e) {
    var pos = getPosMouse(canvas, e);
    posx = pos.x;
    posy = pos.y;
    if (pinta) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
      ctx.fillRect(posx - 4, posy - 4, 8, 8);
    }
  }

  canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    desenha(e);
    red += rm * rf;
    green += gm * gf;
    blue += bm * bf;

    if (red >= 255 || red <= 0) {
      rf *= -1;
      rm = getAleatorio();
    }
    if (green >= 255 || green <= 0) {
      gf *= -1;
      gm = getAleatorio();
    }
    if (blue >= 255 || blue <= 0) {
      bf *= -1;
      bm = getAleatorio();
    }

  };

  document.getElementById("canvas").onmousedown = function() {
    pinta = true;
  };

  document.getElementById("canvas").onmouseup = function() {
    pinta = false;
  }

  function getPosMouse(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
  }

  function getAleatorio() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  }
}

init();
```

```css
.centralizado {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas class="centralizado" id="canvas">your browser is nope!</canvas>
</div>
```

> Fonte: [É possível salvar o canvas como imagem, e enviar ao servidor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202917/5878)

#### Exemplo de conversão de texto para imagem com Canvas:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("receipt");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const messages = [
  "################################",
  "Central Jogos",
  "################################",
  "Apostador: test",
  "Valor apostado: R$ 5,00",
  "Valor de retorno: R$ 6,15",
  "Data da aposta: 19/02/2017 15:07",
  "Quantidade de jogos: 1",
  "--------------------------------",
  "Vasco X Flamengo",
  "Empate: 1.23",
  "10/03/2017 15:30",
  "================================",
  "Cambista: Cambista Teste",
  "Telefone: (82) 9977-8877"
];

context.font = "12px Courier new";

y = 12;
for (var i in messages) {
  context.fillText(messages[i], 0, y);
  y += 18;
}

document.getElementById("result").src = context.canvas.toDataURL();
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 16px
}

div {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Canvas:</h1>
  <canvas id="receipt" width="230" height="270"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Resultado:</h1>
  <img id="result" alt="Receipt" />
</div>
```

> Fonte: [Transformar texto de uma string em imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185231/5878)

#### Exemplo de animação criado com Canvas e jQuery

```js
var c = document.createElement("canvas"),
  $ = c.getContext("2d");

var w = window.innerWidth,
  h = window.innerHeight;

c.width = w;
c.height = h;

c.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, true);

document.body.appendChild(c);

var part;  //particle 
var meshW = 100;  //mesh width
var dispX = -50;  //x disposition
var dispY = -100;  //y disposition
var partX = 0;  //particle x
var partY = 0;  //particle y
var partIndX = 0;  //particle index x
var partIndY = 0;  //particle index y

var col0 = "rgb(74, 1, ";  //shading color-starts
var col1 = "rgb(0, 3, ";

var partList = [];  //particle array
var gridW = w + meshW;   //grid width 
var gridH = h + meshW * 2;  //grid height

while(partY < gridH)
{
 while(partX < gridW)
 {
  part = new Object(partX, partY, partIndX, partIndY);
  partList.push(part);

  partX += meshW;
  partIndX++;
 }
 
 partX = 0;
 partIndX = 0;
 partY += meshW;
 partIndY++;
}


var partArrayL= partList.length;
var rowCt = Math.ceil( gridW / meshW );  //row count
var colCt = Math.ceil( gridH / meshW );  //column count

$.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

for(var i = 0; i < partArrayL; ++i)
{
 part = partList[i];
 part.next = partList[i + 1];
 
 if(part.indX % rowCt != rowCt - 1 && part.indY != colCt - 1)
 {
  part.connectAll.push(partList[i + 1]);
  part.connectAll.push(partList[i + rowCt + 1]);
  part.connectAll.push(partList[i + rowCt]);
  part.ready();
 }
}

var int = setInterval(intHandler, 1000 / 30);

function mouseDown()
{
 if(int != undefined)
 {
  clearInterval(int);
  int = undefined;
 }
 else
 {
  int = setInterval(intHandler, 1000 / 30);  
 }
}

part = partList[0];

function intHandler()
{
 $.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
 
 while(part != undefined)
 {
  part.draw();
  part = part.next;
 }
 
 part = partList[0];
 
 while(part != undefined)
 {
  part.fill();
  part = part.next;
 }
 
 part = partList[0];
}

function Object(pX, pY, pIndX, pIndY)
{
 this.distort = 50;
 
 this.x = dispX + pX + ( Math.random() - Math.random() ) * this.distort;
 this.y = dispY + pY + ( Math.random() - Math.random() ) * this.distort;
 this.indX = pIndX;
 this.indY = pIndY;
 this.color = "hsla(261, 55%, 5%, 1)";  //part border color
  
 this.size = 2;
 this.next = undefined;
 
 this.tracker = (Math.PI / 2) + this.indX * .5;
 this.diffX = Math.random();
 this.diffY = Math.random();
 this.speed = .1;
 this.vol = 30;  //volume  (higher #, more movement)
 
 this.colRngDiff = 70;  //shading variation
  //color range > changing the 225 to vals between 0 and 255, as well as the color range difference # above,  will change base color
 this.colRng = (225 - this.colRngDiff) + Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colRngDiff);
 
 this.draw = function()
 { 
  this.tracker += this.speed;
  this.tracker = this.tracker == 1 ? 0 : this.tracker;
  
  this.x += (Math.sin( this.tracker ) * this.speed) * this.vol;
  this.y += (Math.cos( this.tracker ) * this.speed) * this.vol;
  
 }

 this.readyW = 0;  //start point
 this.readyW1 = 0;

 this.ready = function()
 {
  this.readyW = Math.abs(this.connectAll[0].x - this.x);
  this.readyW1 = Math.abs(this.connectAll[1].x - this.connectAll[2].x);
 }

 
 this.connectAll = [];
 
 this.connect = function()
 {
  if(this.connectAll.length > 0)
  {   
   $.beginPath();
   $.strokeStyle = this.color;
   $.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
 
   for(var j = 0; j < this.connectAll.length; ++j) 
    $.lineTo(this.connectAll[j].x, this.connectAll[j].y);
     
   $.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
   $.lineTo(this.connectAll[1].x, this.connectAll[1].y);
   $.stroke();
  }
 }
 
 this.calcW = 0;
 this.calcW1 = 0;
 
 this.fill = function()
 {  
  if(this.connectAll.length > 0)
  { 
   this.calcW = Math.abs(this.connectAll[0].x - this.x);
   this.calcW1 = Math.abs(this.connectAll[1].x - this.connectAll[2].x); 
      
   $.beginPath();
   $.fillStyle = col0 + (Math.floor((this.readyW / this.calcW) * this.colRng)).toString() + ")";
   
   $.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
   $.lineTo(this.connectAll[2].x, this.connectAll[2].y);
   $.lineTo(this.connectAll[1].x, this.connectAll[1].y);
   $.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
   
   $.fill();
   
   
   $.beginPath();
   $.fillStyle = col1 + (Math.floor((this.readyW1 / this.calcW1) * this.colRng)).toString() + ")";
   
   $.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
   $.lineTo(this.connectAll[1].x, this.connectAll[1].y);
   $.lineTo(this.connectAll[0].x, this.connectAll[0].y);
   $.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
   
   $.fill();
  }  
 }
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Fonte: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/canvas-shape-and-color-effects/

#### Exemplo de 'jogo' criado no Canvas

```js
  var C2D, W, H, RC;
  var fps = 24;
  var mspf = 1000 / fps;
  var updateInterval;
  var quit = false;

  function main() {
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (c.getContext) {
      initializeCanvas(c);
      var P = new Player(8);
      var L = new Level();
      RC = new RayCaster(C2D, W, H, 4, L, P, input);
      if (initializeLevel()) {
        trace('map loaded successfully.');
        trace("now casting...");
        trace("  \'a\' - turn left");
        trace("  \'d\' - turn right");
        trace("  \'w\' - step forward");
        trace("  \'s\' - step backward");
        trace("  \'q\' - stop casting");
        updateInterval = window.setInterval("update()", mspf);
      }
      else {
        trace("map failed to load");
      }
    }

    else {
      trace('sorry.. you\'ll need a browser that supports the canvas tag,');
      trace('like Safari or Firefox 1.5+ to see this demo.');
    }
  }

  function initializeCanvas(c) {
      C2D = c.getContext('2d');
      C2D.lineWidth = 1;
      C2D.globalAlpha = 1;
      C2D.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
      W = c.width;
      H = c.height;
      trace('canvas initialized');
  }

  function initializeLevel() {
    var mapCells_x = 16;
    var mapCells_y = 16;
    var M = '' +
      '################' +
      '#  @@@@@       #' +
      '#  @   @ % # % #' +
      '#  @       #   #' +
      '#  @  @@       #' +
      '#    &         #' +
      '#   &   P      #' +
      '#  &      &&   #' +
      '#              #' +
      '#  ##  #@%#@%  #' +
      '#  #        #  #' +
      '#  ###      #  #' +
      '#  #        #  #' +
      '#  ######## #  #' +
      '#              #' +
      '################';

    trace('submitting map...');
    return RC.loadMap(M, mapCells_x, mapCells_y);
  }

  function update() {
    if (input.quit) {
      input.quit = false;
      window.clearInterval(updateInterval);
      trace('raycaster halted.');
    }
    else {
      RC.update();
    }
  }
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://mdn.github.io/canvas-raycaster/trace.js"></script>
<link href="https://mdn.github.io/canvas-raycaster/trace.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://mdn.github.io/canvas-raycaster/input.js"></script>
<script src="https://mdn.github.io/canvas-raycaster/Player.js"></script>
<script src="https://mdn.github.io/canvas-raycaster/Level.js"></script>
<script src="https://mdn.github.io/canvas-raycaster/RayCaster.js"></script>

<body onload="main();" onkeydown="press(event);" onkeyup="release(event);">
<div id="trace" class="window"><ul><li>RayCaster v.0.0.1</li></ul></div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
</body>
```

> Fonte: https://mdn.github.io/canvas-raycaster/

Comment: Nossa, muito legal mesmo, adorei o jogo, mesmo que seja simples. A explicação como sempre excelente +1 =) Pena que minha criatividade tá falhando ultimamente

Comment: Eu estava pesquisando por exemplos em canvas, mas depois da sua resposta, desisti de procurar. +1

Comment: Acho interessante destacar que `canvas` tem sua etimologia do tecido usado para se pintar quadros

Comment: Boa resposta! já me foi útil pra converter texto em imagem =]

Answer (score 3):

A tag  é como se fosse um quadro em branco, esperando para ser pintado com um poderoso pincel chamado Javascript. :)

Na verdade, é muito mais do que isso, com a tag  você consegue renderizar imagens, desenhar elementos complexos e criar animações.

O bom mesmo é a possibilidade de fazer tudo isso sem usar qualquer plugin como Flash Player ou Silverlight, é só HTML e Javascript.

Exemplos

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Seu Navegador não suporta tag canvas</canvas>
```

```js
    function draw() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
        ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);
      }
    }
```

```html
 <body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
 </body>
```

[**Mais exemplos**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

Answer (score 2):

> Em HTML5 Canvas é focado em desenho/processamento de imagens com
> contexto 2D e 3D
>
> Definição por @Gabriel Gartz

Basicamente são formas geométricas mas também é composta por imagens (sprites), o melhor exemplo para isso são os jogos escritos em HTML5. No caso dos jogos, escrito lado a lado com o javascript para a atualização do canvas.

Você imaginar que o canvas é um espaço pronto para desenhar.

Um exemplo fácil são os [Doodles do Google](https://www.google.com/doodles), normalmente feitos em HTML5.

Exemplo retirado da Web.

https://codepen.io/sethmcl/pen/duGsh

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x = 50;
var y = 50;

function clearScreen() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}

function drawSquare(x, y) {
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
}

function draw() {
  clearScreen();
  drawSquare(x, y);
  x = x + 5;
  setTimeout(draw, 50);
}

draw();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

É fácil de concluir também que esse recurso, o canvas, substituiu o nosso velho Flash. E obviamente por se tratar de uma renderização nativa e não precisar de plugins de terceiros, uma melhora na performance.

Answer (score 0):

É uma tag `HTML5` que permite você possa acessar métodos para criação de formas geométricas, fazer animações, etc.

Por exemplo:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("minhaCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 80, 80);
```

```html
<canvas id="minhaCanvas"></canvas>
```